# Where can I go to change the vertical drop out for a horizontal drop out?

Tags: frames

I have an aluminum road bike frame that I want to use to build a fixed gear. My problem with this frame is that it has vertical drop out and no derailleur hanger. Fr

Comment: Yep, you'd have to find a skilled frame builder.

Answer (score 8):

You don't necessarily need horizontal drop-outs to make a fixie. You could also get an eccentric hub such as [this one](http://www.whiteind.com/rearhubs/singlespeedhubs.html).  This allows the chain slack to be taken up without using horizontal drop outs. They also have eccentric bottom brackets but I think they require a special frame.

Comment: I've always figured that a fixie required an eccentric bike builder.

Comment: Just get a standard chain tensioner if you're gonna do that

Comment: Sheldon quoth thou shouldst not use chain tensioners with fixed gear (single speed free OK, but not single speed fixed): http://sheldonbrown.com/harris/singlespeed.html#tensioners

Comment: @hillsons As JonS mentioned, you can't use a chain tensioner with a fixie. And you don't need one with an eccentric hub or bottom bracket. The eccentricity of the hub is what tensions the chain.

Answer (score 4):

You would have to go to someone that knows how to weld aluminum to weld you on a new dropout. I don't think you want to do that. It would be cheaper to find a frame / entire bike designed to be a single speed in the first place.